# ChartJS: How to align top labels with bottom labels?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I have a chart - made with chartJS - that displays monthly data. There is a top label to indicate each new month at the top the chart. It is generated in xAxes with:

```js
{
          position: "top",
          ticks: {
            autoSkip: false,
            maxRotation: 0,
            callback: (_, i) => i
          },
```

It works, but the top label is progressively shifting from its bottom label. it's weird. How to fix it?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdUUv.png)
My code is:

```js
   

{
    legend: { display: false },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true,
          ticks: {
            beginAtZero: true,
          },
          gridLines: {
            display: true,
            zeroLineColor: "black,
            zeroLineWidth: 0.5
          }
        }
      ],
      xAxes: [
        {
          offset: true,
          stacked: true,
          ticks: {
            fontColor: "black",
          },
          gridLines: {
            color: "transparent",
            zeroLineColor: "black,
            z: 1
          }
        },
        {
          position: "top",
          ticks: {
            autoSkip: false,
            maxRotation: 0,
            callback: (_, i) => i
          },
          gridLines: {
            drawBorder: false,
            display: true,
            lineWidth: 0.5
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Could you show more of your source code? It's also unclear from the graphic what this chart would look like if it weren't cropped. As such the source code would reveal (?) what the data was to generate it.

Comment: I have updated my original post with full code and complete screenshot.

Comment: Okay from that graphic -- and I dont say this to say you dont see it otherwise -- you basically want to horizontally center the top label?

Comment: Hi, I want to align the top labels (0,1,2, etc.) with the bars' left-borders, so everything looks clean & perfectly aligned, and not like two grids obeying their own spacing rules.

Comment: Im not familiar with the docs. But i did want to clarify what you are after for future responders. You want the top label centered between the previous's `x` and the next `x` essentially. Or said differently, between the current node's `x1` and the next node's `x1'.